# Parameters grid search with different text sets for dictionary creation and cross validation

Tags: python, email, pandas, scikit-learn, text-classification

I have to train a classifier for spam detecting.

**Dataset that I have.**

At hand I have one labeled dataset of emails with `[text, class]`.
And I also have a lot of emails without class labels.

**What I want to do.**

I want to use `gridsearchcv()` function to estimate the best hyperparameters for my model. And one of the parameters is related to dictionary creation (like 1-gram or 2-gram, min frequency etc.). What I want `gridsearchcv()` function to do is to use the whole emails dataset (emails with labels + emails without labels) for `CountVectorizer` in my pipeline to create dictionary. But I want it to test the result only on the labeled emails. So, basically I want to use the whole dataset for creation of dictionary and I want to estimate parameters using cross validation only on labeled dataset.

Any help will be apprectiated :)

**Update:**

**important:** To address @AndreasMueller answer: the results will be different because I also tune parameters of CountVectorizer and I use inverse document frequency. So, I am searching for a way to make my classifier more general by also including the unlabeled data.

This is what I have by now:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
('features', FeatureUnion([
    ('words', Pipeline([
        ('vect',  CountVectorizer()),
        ('frequency_transform',  TfidfTransformer())
    ])),            
    ('url_feature',  Contains_URL_Transformer()),
    ('html_feature', Contains_HTML_Transformer()),
    ('length_feature', Text_Length_Transformer()),
    ('response_feature', Contains_Re_Transformer())
    ])),
('clf',  SVC())
])

parameters = {
'features__words__vect__min_df': (1, 3, 5),
'features__words__vect__token_pattern': (r"\b[^\W\d_]+\b",),
'features__words__vect__binary': (False,),
'features__words__frequency_transform__use_idf' : (True,),
#'vect__max_features': (None, 5000, 10000, 50000),
'features__words__vect__ngram_range': ((1, 1), (1, 2)),  # unigrams or bigrams
'clf__C': (1, 5, 10),
'clf__kernel': ('linear', 'rbf')
#'tfidf__use_idf': (True, False)
#'tfidf__norm': ('l1', 'l2'),
#'clf__alpha': (0.00001, 0.000001),
#'clf__penalty': ('l2', 'elasticnet'),
#'clf__n_iter': (10, 50, 80),
}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, n_jobs=-1, verbose=1)

data_column = numpy.asarray(data['text'])

data_column = numpy.append(data_column, ['test'])

grid_search.fit(data_column, numpy.asarray(data['class']))

best_parameters = grid_search.best_estimator_.get_params()

for param_name in sorted(parameters.keys()):
    print("\t%s: %r" % (param_name, best_parameters[param_name]))
```

But I also have `unlabled_data['text']`. How can I add the mix of `data['text']` and `unlabled_data['text']` to the pipeline in order to create the dictionary (and estimate the parameters) from that mix but to test it on the labeled data. The problem is that when I do `grid_search.fit()` it uses the provided data set to create dictionary and I see no way to put there all the emails.

Comment: Which part are you stuck on? Tried anything? The online docs are pretty clear

Comment: @EdChum, I am stuck at the pipeline part. I updated my question. I will be very glad if you point me out the docs where I can find the answer.

Comment: I think this is a very reasonable question, and the best solution I can come up with is a bit disappointing. It might be worth bringing the question up on the scikit-learn-general mailing list.

Comment: @joeln, nonetheless, thank you.

Comment: To make this clearer, you should edit the question to highlight the fact that your parameter search includes CountVectorizer parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution solution forces the fit data to be constant irrespective of the cross-validation data:

```
X_all = full dataset

class MyVectorizer(sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return super(MyVectorizer, self).fit(X_all)
    def fit_transform(self, X, y=None):
        return super(MyVectorizer, self).fit(X_all).transform(X)
```

Use this in place of the `'words'` sub-pipeline above.

---

An arguably less hacky, but much more complicated, solution is along the lines of:

- Concatenate the labelled and unlabelled data, setting the label of
  the latter's instances to `-1`
- Use a custom cross validation generator that always keeps the unlabeled instances in the training set.
- Use a wrapper around the post-feature-extraction part of the pipeline (here SVC) to remove the unlabelled data (note you cannot just
  implement this as a `Transformer`). (Perhaps extending from SVC is simpler, a bit like what `MyVectorizer` does above, but without using the global data hack.)

An advantage of this approach is that it applies regardless of the `GridSearchCV` input (as opposed to the hack of injecting the full data via a global variable).

Example code:

```
def semisupervised_stratified_kfold(y, *args, **kwargs):
    labeled_idx = np.flatnonzero(y != -1)
    unlabeled_idx = np.flatnonzero(y == -1)
    for train, test in StratifiedKFold(y[labelled_idx], *args, **kwargs):
        train = np.concatenate([unlabeled_idx, labeled_idx.take(train)])
        test = labeled_idx.take(test)
        yield train, test

from sklearn.utils.metaestimators import if_delegate_has_method
class StripUnlabelled(sklearn.base.BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self, estimator):
        self.estimator = sklearn.base.clone(estimator)
    def fit(self, X, y, **kwargs):
        return self.estimator.fit()
    @if_delegate_has_method(delegate='estimator')
    def predict(self, X):
        return self.estimator.predict(X)
    # and similar for decision_function, predict_proba, score, etc.
```

Then set `GridSearchCV`'s `cv` parameter to the custom generator, wrap `StripUnlabeled` around the `SVC` instance, and prefix SVC parameter names with `estimator__`

This will actually not build the TFIDF model on all the data, but will use all the unlabeled data plus all the training folds of the labeled data.

Also, note that all similar solutions using `Pipeline` will be quite inefficient, given the repeated work is not cached when parameters are changed downstream, although there are generic solutions that have been proposed for caching parts of pipelines.

Comment: why not just fit a vectorizer on the data, then use a fixed vocabulary when creating the vectorizer?

Comment: Because OP wants to incorporate document frequency statistics from the overall corpus too, but only with respect to a vocabulary determined *by grid search parameters*.

Comment: hum, right, I didn't realize that he is grid-searching the Vectorizer parameters, too

Comment: @joeln, yes. This is exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that using a pre-specified dictionary. However, that wouldn't matter. If words don't appear in the training data, their coefficient will be zero, so adding them to the vocabulary does nothing.

Comment: I think the idea is to use a TFIDF model that is derived from a larger corpus.

Comment: I'm not sure as he uses count vectorizer, then TFIDF transformer. Your solution applied to CountVectorizer will  not change anything.